# AngularJS: Filter date with sql date string format

Tags: sql, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, datefilter

I need to add a date filter which have a date property with date string value("2015-10-15T20:00:00.000Z"). This is a huge list so I can't convert every object to Date and then filter. I believe there will be any alternative to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this filter:

```js
angular.module('yourmodule').filter('datetime', function($filter) {
    return function(input) {
        var t = input.split(/[- :]/);

        // Apply each element to the Date function
        var d = new Date(t[0], t[1] - 1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
        console.log(d);
        return d;
    };

});
```

Comment: I actually need to filter out the date range without todays date. I have added one ng-show with a function passing each fromDate and toDate.
new Date("2015-10-15T20:00:00.000Z") will give JS date object and return curresponding value.

Thanks